# xaml TextBlock in listview not aligning right

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to align the column headers to the left and the detail in the column to the right.
The header I get right, but the detail (textBlock) does not want to align to the right. Please help. Here is my code

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
 ItemsSource="{Binding Trans}" 
 Grid.Row="2"
 Grid.Column="0"
 Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
 MaxHeight="230">
 <!--Align column header to the left-->
 <ListView.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
  </Style>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
   <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
   </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Amount" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=Amount, StringFormat=N2}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: you can do as @Sajeetharan said setting Width="200"   and then aligning your text to the right .
your textblock itself would still be aligned to the left the reason for that , which i know by observing in snoop , that the ContentPresenter inside ListViewItem is set to Left and that's why it's always only the width of your text and to the left .
it was set locally , so it was probably done in the code of the GridViewRowPresenter.

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following attribute to text block and check

> TextAlignment="Right"
>   to  TextBlock node in Data template

Also if that didn't solve please try adding

> Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right" to listview item Style

Comment: HorizontalContentAlignment will work in this case , 
but what if would add additional content

Comment: @eran otzap i think he added HorizontalAlignment = right but not TextAlignment="Right" on his Textblock elementmarkup

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
       <GridView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <GridViewColumn Header="Amount"  >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <StackPanel Width="200"  >
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Black"  TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=Amount, StringFormat=N2}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with something like this :

```
<ListView Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">

    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
           <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>         
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
           <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/> <!-- Redundent -->      
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>

    <ListView.View>
           <GridView>                               
            <GridViewColumn Header="Amount" >
            <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Background="AliceBlue" Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </Grid>         
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>

            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Background="AliceBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=Amount}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```